# json-jackson array parsing

Tags: android, arrays, jackson

the json like this

```
   {
      "resultCode": "0000",
      "resultMsg": "",
      "pageCount": "6",
      "curPage": "1",
      "infoItems": [
        {
          "sID": "268",
          "location": "222",
          "unit": "",
          "time": "2012-11-02 17:51:46",
          "longitude": "111",
          "latitude": "222",
          "reason": "some",
          "dealContent": ""
        },
        {
          "sID": "267",
          "location": "fgg",
          "unit": "yyg",
          "time": "2012-11-02 17:49:14",
          "longitude": "111",
          "latitude": "222",
          "reason": "some",
          "dealContent": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

How could I decode it to java class?

I write a class like

```
public class UploadedInfoObjEx {
    public String resultCode;
    public String resultMsg;
    public String pageCount;
    public String curPage;
    public Items[] infoItems;

    public class Items {
        private String sID;
        private String location;
        private String unit;
        private String longitude;
        private String latitude;
        private String reason;
        private String time;
        private String dealContent;
    }

}
```

and read json

```
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            UploadedInfoObjEx uploadedInfoObjEx = mapper.readValue(jsonString, UploadedInfoObjEx.class);
```

the error is

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.rayboot.wl.object.UploadedInfoObjEx$Items]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
```

at [Source: java.io.StringReader@4150c480; line: 1, column: 81] (through reference chain: com.rayboot.wl.object.UploadedInfoObjEx["infoItems"])

anyone could help me?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to make the variables in your `Items` class public. You may also need to make it static:

```
public static class Items {
    public String sID;
    public String location;
    public String unit;
    public String longitude;
    public String latitude;
    public String reason;
    public String time;
    public String dealContent;
}
```

If that doesn't work you could try moving `Items` to its own file.

Comment: Either make them public; add `@JsonProperty` annotation; or change default introspection visibility to "see" private fields too. Many ways to achieve this.